# Persistent Bottom Navigation Bar Flutter on Route to Screens

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-bottomnavigation

I looked online but there are various cases I've tried but failed, it seems so easy yet so difficult is some cases. I have a BottomNavBar in which I made a list of Widgets I want to render, and it works ok (not sure if it's the right approach though). I have a `Drawer` and when I press on one of the menu items, I want to render that Widget but with the BottomNavBar being persistent. In other words, almost all screens should render with a persistent BottomNavBar. Here is the code:

Bottom Navigation Bar:

```
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'bottom_navbar_screen';
  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0; // the starting screen (can be any of them by changing the starting index)
  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Screen1(),
    Screen2(),
    Screen3(),
    Screen4(),
    Screen5(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: Tab1,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: Tab2,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem( 
            label:Tab3,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: Tab4,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: Tab5,
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now at some point of the app, I have a `Drawer` and when I press on one of the menu item inside the Drawer that sends me to let's say Screen2, I just get sent to Screen2 but without the BottomNavBar showing (which is logical but I want to show it, hence the problem I got). I tried with `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen2(index: 1),),);` and initializing the index inside the BottomNavBar but failed. Is there a better solution for this type of problem I have?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: its a really weird design to have this and not really logical, I think you need to add the bottom navigation bar in every screen you navigate to, you can wrap this bottom navigation bar with a hero widget so when navigating from screen to screen it will animate the position, but since they are in the same position you will get the effect that it seems like it stayed in the same position.

Comment: Weird meaning my design is weird or generally `BottomNavigationBar` is weird? And why not logical if you mean my design? I don't mind the comments, just a explanation of why are they bad is more helpful than just saying it's weird.